Issue with NC contact behavior when converting from Allen Bradley to Siemens
Image I have an issue. We're currently rewriting a program from Allen Bradley to Siemens and I've noticed something strange. How can bit B3:2 turn true if it’s blocked by an NC (Normally Closed) contact that gets activated right there? If it worked in Allen Bradley, how will it work in Siemens?
I don`t understand how it must be working

If it isn't set by the contact it is probably set somewhere else? B3:2 is marked as latch so it can be set/unset from different places.

@MarkusSafar Yes, it is also set/reset in other places, but the same questionable method is used there as well. This variable is for the safety stop, so I’m concerned that it could cause issues.

I am not sure I get your point. You have a variable and that variable has a state. It is set whenever B3:48 is interrupted (=open)(even if it closes again). As I understand it you are wondering because the variable is true although you assume that B3:48 never opens, right?

@MarkusSafar I'm concerned that B3:48 might never open. There are doubts whether it will open during one iteration of the controller's cycle or not. I suspect that the developers intended to implement a signal on the rising edge this way. However, I'm not sure if it will work correctly on a Siemens microcontroller as it did on an Allen Bradley microcontroller.

There are plenty of users fluent with AB & Siemens on the SIOS forum:
https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/us/en/
Such questions usually get plenty of expert answers.

Ah ok, now I get your concern. I guess Cliff Pennalligen has given a valid lead in the right direction with his comment about the forum, you might be off there as this sight is mainly focused around programming and software development, not PLCs.

Old logix500 aye ;)  S7-1200 and 1500 would scan the ladder you posted in the same order.  So you may perform a direct port (replacing the variables as required):

TIA Portal does not allow branches containing 'output-type' instructions to be joined back up, hence the open ends on the right side.  But it is functionally equivalent.
